# What is the difference between Project and Faceted Project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Just feeling curious that what the difference is for the 'Project' and 'Faceted Project'? Both are in the File->New->Others->General folder. I tried both of them and both only give me an empty project folder.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the Eclipse website:

> Faceted Project Framework facilitates treating Eclipse projects as composed of units of functionality (called facets) that can be easily added or removed by users. The technology was originally developed in Eclipse Web Tools Platform, but is in the process of turning into an independent project as a way to broaden appeal.

I understand it as "multiple projects in one".

Comment: Its correct but in short it will give the functionality of adding JET nature to the project

Answer (score 1):

You will find the clear details about it at this [LINK](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcfacets.html)

Answer (score 0):

> A Facet is an Eclipse WebTools Project concept which essentially means
> a capability attached to an Eclipse project.
>
> When a project is created, various information is assembled to:
>
> specify the type of project, add standard libraries, set compiler
> options, control publishing tasks, set the build path and/or add an
> annotation processor. This information is specified with facets.
>
> Facets have version numbers. Not all facet version numbers can be
> changed (e.g., a facet available in only one version of software can
> not have other version numbers).
>
> Some facet version numbers are inter-dependent (e.g., if you choose
> the facet Java Annotation Processing, you must also have Java version
> 5.0 selected since Java versions 1.3 and 1.4 did not support annotation processing).
>
> The facet choices vary depending on the project type. For example, web
> service facets are not available when creating an EJB project.

[image]

Reference: https://datacadamia.com/ide/eclipse/facet